Input shape argument isn't recognized for cvnn with cvnn libary
I have a problem with my little code project, where I want to program a complex valued neural network, which can take real number and complex numbers as inputs and approximate a simple function f(x,y) = x^2-3y. I've created a few (18) training and testing samples to use the network. The network takes 3 input values: "[input_x, input_y], z", where z is the value from the function with the values input_x and input_y. I've also created a custom tf-layer to make the output of the nn as I want.
I have a problem with the shape argument in the ComplexInput.
Code:
import tensorflow as tf
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
import cmath as cm
import cvnn.layers as complex_layers
import custom_output_layer
import keras

# # f(x,y) = z = x**2-3*y --> function to learn (3-dim) : f(x,y)=x^2-3y

data_train_x = np.array([1, complex(4,3).real, complex(5,3).real, 6, 3, 7, complex(1,1).real, 3, complex(9,8).real, 9, 5, complex(9,0).real, 5, 3, complex(1,2).real, 2, complex(7,7).real, 9], dtype=np.complex64) # input data x
data_train_y = np.array([4, complex(4,3).imag, complex(5,3).imag, 5, 3, 8, complex(1,1).imag, 4, complex(9,8).imag, 9, 6, complex(9,0).imag, 3, 4, complex(1,2).imag, 8, complex(7,7).imag, 1], dtype=np.complex64) # input data y
data_train_z = np.array([]) # input data z --> gets calculated automtically

#calculates the z variable based on x and y
for x, y in zip(data_train_x, data_train_y):
    result = x**2 - 3*y
    data_train_z = np.append(data_train_z, result)

data_test_x = np.array([10, 15, 24, 31, 12, 25, 26, 96, 5, 2, 23, 11], dtype=np.complex64) # test data x
data_test_y = np.array([12, 18, 27, 34, 14, 29, 30, 99, 7, 4, 22, 13], dtype=np.complex64) # test data y
data_test_z = np.array([]) # test data z --> gets calculated automtically

#calculates the z variable based on x and y
for x, y in zip(data_test_x, data_test_y):
    result = x**2 - 3*y
    data_test_z = np.append(data_test_z, result)

model = tf.keras.models.Sequential([
    complex_layers.ComplexInput(shape=(2,), dtype='complex64'), # here is the problem with the shape argument
    complex_layers.ComplexDense(2, activation='linear'), #ComplexDense layer 
    custom_output_layer(1)
])


def l2_loss_function(z_true, z_pred):
    return tf.reduce_sum(tf.square(z_true - z_pred))

print(model.summary())

model.compile(optimizer='SGD', loss=l2_loss_function)
model.fit([data_train_x, data_train_y], data_train_z, epochs=100)

predictions = model.predict([data_test_x, data_test_y])
print("predictions: ", predictions, "\n real data: ", data_test_z)

When I try to run the code, this error appears:
Argument `input_shape` is deprecated. Use `shape` instead.
  warnings.warn(
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Users/username/Desktop/Programmierung/Komplex-(gewertetes)-NN/main.py", line 34, in <module>
    complex_layers.ComplexInput(shape=(2,), dtype='complex64'),
    ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "/Users/username/Desktop/Programmierung/Komplex-(gewertetes)-NN/.venv/lib/python3.12/site-packages/cvnn/layers/core.py", line 134, in __init__
    super(ComplexInput, self).__init__(input_shape=input_shape, batch_size=batch_size, dtype=dtype,
  File "/Users/username/Desktop/Programmierung/Komplex-(gewertetes)-NN/.venv/lib/python3.12/site-packages/keras/src/layers/core/input_layer.py", line 44, in __init__
    raise ValueError("You must pass a `shape` argument.")
ValueError: You must pass a `shape` argument.


Looks like cvnn lib isn't compatible with newer tf/keras versions. Did you try to downgrade tf/keras? E.g. TF 2.2.0 / Keras 2.3.1 ?

No idn't try that, but I will thx for the hint
